# Core Web Vitals Largest Content paint drops after Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

We have a website and we are using nginx as a reverse proxy for the website.

Before proxy the largest contentful paint timing was better.
[image: Before Reverse Proxy score]

But post reverse proxy largest contentful paint has dropped badly.

This is the site after reverse proxy https://revanshkapoor.com/.
Major concern is LCP score.
[image: After Reverse Proxy score]

We have also tested by moving all static assets to cloud-front CDN but LCP is not showing any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots in your original post, it appears you're running this assessment in Lighthouse, which is a tool that provides lab data. ([This is a helpful post](https://web.dev/lab-and-field-data-differences/) that helps to explain what lab data is and why it's different than field data, if you're unfamiliar.) In order to understand what your website's actual performance is for end users, you'll need to [gather](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) and analyze field data.

In the absence of field data, though, my intuition tells me that the addition of a reverse proxy *may* be having a negative effect on your site's [time to first byte (TTFB)](https://web.dev/), which precedes other rendering metrics such as Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) and First Contentful Paint (FCP). A cursory glance at network timings in Chrome's Devtools for your domain shows a high TTFB ([image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvWgH.png)).

However, this is just a one-off test from my device, and it's not as authoritative of a performance assessment as an analysis of sufficient field data. Even so, [this WebPageTest run](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/220221_BiDcR5_D7N/) on a simulated 3G connection shows a high TTFB value.

I would not focus solely on your site's TTFB to lower other metrics. If you filter audits to what is relevant to LCP, [this Lighthouse report from the WebPageTest run] linked above shows that you have several opportunities to improve this metric (and others) on the front end ([image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULp8G.png)).

The biggest opportunity here is to reduce the amount of render-blocking resources you are sending. It appears your website is running on Drupal, and there may be a number of plugins or theme-specific optimizations you can make to improve your LCP and other related metrics, quite possibly by concatenating CSS resources or removing unused resources.